# More Leaking Code help?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, sdk, memory-leaks

```
-(IBAction)customizeYourGameButtonClicked:(id)sender {
 [self playHumanHitSound];

 self.customizeYourGameViewController = [[CustomizeYourGameViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"CustomizeYourGameViewController" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController
     pushViewController:customizeYourGameViewController animated:YES];
 [customizeYourGameViewController release];
}
```

Can't understand why this is leaking.  I set customizeYourGameViewController as a property and synthesized it.

Comment: Could you edit your post to make sure your code is formatted like code? Either put 4 spaces in front of each code line, or just select the stuff and hit the "Code Sample" button in the formatting bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `customizeYourGameViewController` is a property on your class. Is it set to retain? If so, the @synthesized setter for customizeYourGameViewController is doing a retain and you'll need to release somewhere.

Although, thinking about this, I'm wondering: Why is `customizeYourGameViewController` a property? Unless you're communicating with the controller elsewhere, it should just be a local variable.

```
-(IBAction)customizeYourGameButtonClicked:(id)sender {
 [self playHumanHitSound];

 id customizeYourGameViewController = [[CustomizeYourGameViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"CustomizeYourGameViewController" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController
     pushViewController:customizeYourGameViewController animated:YES];
 [customizeYourGameViewController release];
}
```

Then remove the ivar and remove the property.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating `CustomizeYourGameViewController` but not releasing it. Makes the changes below.

```
[[[CustomizeYourGameViewController alloc] nitWithNibName:@"CustomizeYourGameViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

and you can get rid of the final

```
[customizeYourGameViewController release];
```

I'm not sure what it's doing (do you have a iVar named `customizeYourGameViewController`), but it's probably not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: The last line of the sample is [customizeYourGameViewController release];. Adding an autorelease might very work around the leak, but it's not going to correct the logic.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize he'd formatted it AFTER posting. Sorry to jump on you!